# Flutter : create a app specific folder in phone storage using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I need to create a app specific folder in storage but error returns "access denied". When i searched about it i found that there is no way to create app specific folder directly in storage from android 11.

```
  Future initRecorder() async {
      var directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      var toStringConvertedPath=(directory?.path).toString();

      print(toStringConvertedPath);
      Directory(toStringConvertedPath).create();
```

}

Currently its saving on :
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.survey_app/files

need to save on :
/storage/survey_app/file

Is there any way we can create a folder or there any alternative method to make a folder easily accesible by user in flutter.

Comment: What do you consider to be 'an app specific folder' ? Full path please. And show the code you tried. You do not have to create that folder as it will be created for you when needed.

Comment: @blackapps i need to save the audio recording, so user can come to this app folder and check their audio.But now still its visible by user but in inner folder.

Comment: `to save on : /storage/survey_app/file` Such a path does not and cannot exist. Try `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/survey_app/file` instead.

Comment: i had given path as you mentioned, but still its says creation failed.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED !!!**

What i did is that, i have asked for permission for storage,accessMediaLocation,manageExternalStorage prior to creating the directory.

```
 Future<bool> requestPermission() async {

bool storagePermission = await Permission.storage.isGranted;
bool mediaPermission = await Permission.accessMediaLocation.isGranted;
bool manageExternal = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.isGranted;

if (!storagePermission) {
  storagePermission = await Permission.storage.request().isGranted;
}

if (!mediaPermission) {
  mediaPermission =
      await Permission.accessMediaLocation.request().isGranted;
}

if (!manageExternal) {
  manageExternal =
      await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request().isGranted;
}

bool isPermissionGranted =
    storagePermission && mediaPermission && manageExternal;

if (isPermissionGranted) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}}
```

and in androidManifest.xml add these lines.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Now for creating a directory in storage i.e storage/app_name.

```
Future initRecorder() async {
bool permission = await requestPermission();
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  if (permission) {
    var directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String newPath = "";
    print(directory);
    String convertedDirectoryPath = (directory?.path).toString();
    List<String> paths = convertedDirectoryPath.split("/");
    for (int x = 1; x < convertedDirectoryPath.length; x++) {
      String folder = paths[x];
      if (folder != "Android") {
        newPath += "/" + folder;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    newPath = newPath + "/surveyApp/Audio";
    print(newPath);
    directory = Directory(newPath);
    if (!await directory.exists()) {
      await directory.create(recursive: true);
    }
 
  } else {
    print("permssion denied");
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Please give neccesary permissions");
    return false;
  }
}}
```

Now we can create our app specific directory in the storage level.